# Delete a Google document permanently

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to delete a Google document by using Java APIm it works fine but the document is getting settled in the trash folder. I want the document to get deleted permanently even from trash. Can someone please suggest me a solution on how to work on this?This is the code that I've been using to delete the document.

```
    DocsService docsService = new DocsService(domain);
    URL docURL = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"+resourceId+"?xoauth_requestor_id=" + loginUser);//No I18N
    DocumentListEntry sd=docsService.getEntry(docURL, DocumentListEntry.class);
    sd.delete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting a file permanently is equivalent to sending a DELETE request to the file's edit URL with the query parameter "delete=true" (skip trash):

```
DocsService docsService = new DocsService(domain);
URL docURL = new URL(
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"+resourceId+"?xoauth_requestor_id=" + loginUser + "&delete=true");
docsService.delete(docURL, "<ENTRY'S ETAG>");
```

If you want to by-pass the "etag" check, you can pass the special value `"*"`.